# Change the method of a class from child function.php

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

i want to change the output of a method inside the class of a plugin from the child function.php without changing the plugin's file. The output i want to change is that instead of a common a href, it uses the template button array. The thing is that the output of the method you get is a shortcode (this shortcode below that you can insert to any template you want). I don't know how to change this method from the child function.php. I modded this plugin file, it works, but it means i don't get to update the plugin without loosing the new button.

```
echo do_shortcode( '[bewpi-download-invoice title="Download (PDF) Invoice {formatted_invoice_number}" order_id="' . $order->id . '"]' );
```

Here is the method inside the be-woocommerce-pdf-invoices.php class

```
public function download_invoice_shortcode( $atts ) {
if ( ! isset( $atts['order_id'] ) || 0 === intval( $atts['order_id'] ) ) {
return;
        }

        // by default order status should be Processing or Completed.
        $order = wc_get_order( $atts['order_id'] );
        if ( ! $order->is_paid() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! BEWPI_Invoice::exists( $order->id ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $url = add_query_arg( array(
            'bewpi_action' => 'view',
            'post' => $order->id,
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'view' ),
        ) );

        $invoice = new BEWPI_Invoice( $order->id );
        $tags = array(
            '{formatted_invoice_number}' => $invoice->get_formatted_number(),
            '{order_number}'             => $order->id,
            '{formatted_invoice_date}'   => $invoice->get_formatted_invoice_date(),
            '{formatted_order_date}'     => $invoice->get_formatted_order_date(),
        );
        // find and replace placeholders.
        $title = str_replace( array_keys( $tags ), array_values( $tags ), $atts['title'] );
        // MOD OF THE PLUGIN
        thegem_button(array(
            'tag' => 'a',
            'href' => esc_attr( $url ),
            'text' => esc_html__($title, 'thegem' ),
            'style' => 'outline',
            'size' => 'medium',
            'extra_class' => 'checkout-exit',
            'attributes' => array(
            'value' => esc_attr__( $title, 'thegem' ),
            )
            ), true);
        // ORIGINAL OUTPUT
// printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', esc_attr( $url ), esc_html( $title ) );
    }
```

MOD OF THE PLUGIN is the new code i added. The original output i put it to comment. Any suggestion is welcome of course.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case i am considering this is direct function attached to shortcode. You can create your own shortcode and use it to display what you want. You can try this hack hope it will help you,

```
add_shortcode( 'custom-bewpi-download-invoice', 'print_invoice_func');

function print_invoice_func( $atts ) {
if ( ! isset( $atts['order_id'] ) || 0 === intval( $atts['order_id'] ) ) {
return;
        }

        // by default order status should be Processing or Completed.
        $order = wc_get_order( $atts['order_id'] );
        if ( ! $order->is_paid() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! BEWPI_Invoice::exists( $order->id ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $url = add_query_arg( array(
            'bewpi_action' => 'view',
            'post' => $order->id,
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'view' ),
        ) );

        $invoice = new BEWPI_Invoice( $order->id );
        $tags = array(
            '{formatted_invoice_number}' => $invoice->get_formatted_number(),
            '{order_number}'             => $order->id,
            '{formatted_invoice_date}'   => $invoice->get_formatted_invoice_date(),
            '{formatted_order_date}'     => $invoice->get_formatted_order_date(),
        );
        // find and replace placeholders.
        $title = str_replace( array_keys( $tags ), array_values( $tags ), $atts['title'] );
        // MOD OF THE PLUGIN
        thegem_button(array(
            'tag' => 'a',
            'href' => esc_attr( $url ),
            'text' => esc_html__($title, 'thegem' ),
            'style' => 'outline',
            'size' => 'medium',
            'extra_class' => 'checkout-exit',
            'attributes' => array(
            'value' => esc_attr__( $title, 'thegem' ),
            )
            ), true);
        // ORIGINAL OUTPUT
// printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', esc_attr( $url ), esc_html( $title ) );
    }
```

paste above code in your functions.php and now use this custom shortcode

```
echo do_shortcode( '[custom-bewpi-download-invoice title="Download (PDF) Invoice {formatted_invoice_number}" order_id="' . $order->id . '"]' );
```

Let me know what output it gives to you.

Comment: Yeah it worked like charm!!! Thank you harry for your time. It seems like you are the only one helping me with php code!

Comment: It's easier this way because now i can upgrade my plugin without any concern

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your child theme directory plugin name and plugin file overwrite. Example child-theme-name/plugin-name/example.php